# Is it possible to forge a PHP session ID?

Tags: php, session

If a page checks for the existence of a PHP Session:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['secret'])) {...grant access to EVERYTHING!!!}
```

Is it possible / How could I generate `$_SESSION['secret']` on my machine, in a situation where I don't have access to the page's back-end code? I'm trying to hack into the international space station...

Comment: Well it's very very simple .. you don't .. (oh, merry christmas) :)

Comment: I knew one day aliens would come for our PHP code O.o

Comment: You could steal the session cookie of someone who *is* authenticated.

Comment: Aliens don't use PHP :| .. they use Delphi ..

Comment: I'm afraid ISS runs on Microsoft IIS, that means asp.net, not php...

Comment: Less forging, more hijacking. Still, not something I will explain. Aliens are watching. They scrape stackoverflow to track our tech-progress... ;) Merry christmas!

Comment: @dev-null-dweller I couldn't stop laughing if I were to think to hack a Linux machine and it was Windows all along :P

Comment: @Blender good point! *cough* a friend of mine showed me the Faceniff app ;)

Comment: @iight you probably mean the Facepalm app .. :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot. Or well, you *can* generate a `$_SESSION['secret']` on *your* machine, but it is a different value and you cannot simply put it onto the ISS. You cannot directly alter the `$_SESSION` superglobal unless there's a bug or security hole in the script that lets you.

Comment: I see, so in other words, the session that is stored locally can not affect the session on my server? (since as far as I understand, PHP sessions are created and stored on the server, which is how they differ from good 'ol cookies?)

Comment: @iight, bingo.  There's no way for you to modify the session data on the server without being *on* the server.

Comment: `unless there's a bug or security hole in the script` or extremely bad server configuration (`register_globals`)

Comment: Funny that you mention cookies. That is one part of a session that *is* sent to the client. But it's only used to identify the session in the next request. You may have heard the term *session forging*, which is essentially making up or stealing a session id, putting it in a cookie, allowing you to take over a session. However, there are other ways to block this (like checking IP and browser agent string), and even if you would manage to do this, you would still not have direct access to the `$_SESSION` variable, or any other variable for that matter.

Comment: @dev-null-dweller That indeed is a security hole *outside* of the script. I sincerely hope that the ISS web control interface doesn't have such poor configuration. ;)